# Moving from 1.21 to 1.27 Infobox Broken

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-templates

http://wiki.armaina.com/index.php/Munin
This is just one page but all of my pages that use the infobox on the right there do this on mediawiki 1.27

http://wiki.armaina.com/index.php/Template:Character
This is the template being used for the infoboxes, this is not the wikipedia infobox, it does not use lua, it worked with 1.21 without any additional mods. (I do not want to install Lua, I shouldn't need it, so please don't suggest that) The function of the infobox is such that, if I don't fill in the value it doesn't display at all, and the images I use are supposed to revert to thumbnail size.

All templates and CSS were copied from the original 1.21 build so all I can figure is that the Wiki code itself changed between versions I just don't know what part specifically changed or where to start looking. I'm just hoping someone maybe knows what's breaking this and what I can do to fix it.

FIXED = Needed parser extension active to work. The parser is installed but is off by default as of mediawiki 1.24. Solution was to add this to localsettings.php.

```
require_once "$IP/extensions/ParserFunctions/ParserFunctions.php";
$wgPFEnableStringFunctions = true;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the [ParserFunctions](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:ParserFunctions) extension. Given that it couldn't have worked without that in 1.21 either, you probably made some mistake when copying the old configuration.

Comment: No mistake, the function was installed by default in past version 1.18 the only difference is that after 1.24 is that it had to be manually turned on by adding this to localsettings.php

require_once "$IP/extensions/ParserFunctions/ParserFunctions.php";
$wgPFEnableStringFunctions = true;

It worked in the older version without any changes because it was turned on by default and I never realized it was a part of that. So thank you SO MUCH for pointing me in the right direction, everything works perfectly now!